# WIX multiple copies of same file in msi but only one will be installed

Tags: wix, wix3.5

i have multiple environments, build, test, prod etc.

i'd like to create a single installer in wix, which can hold multiple machine.config files. then based on the feature value passed in through the command line only one file will be installed.

conceptualy it sounds easy but i receive an ICE30 error stating that

"ICE30: The target file 'btfrgsa_|[FILENAME]' is installed in '[TARGETDIR]\NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR64\CONFIG\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'MachineConfigs.WS' and 'MachineConfigs.APP'. This breaks component reference counting.".

what would be the best way to do this?

thanks

Semaj

Comment: Did you try looking at Condition statements. That might be even easier then the answer you selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of approaches:

1. Create several features and components with files of different names ( 1.config, 2.config ) and then use the CopyFile element to cause x.config to be copied to the real file name. )   This will result in x.config and real.config being deployed but it's harmless and the uninstall will work cleanly.
2. Identify the differences between the x.configs and use XML changes to apply them at install time using xpath statements.

Comment: +1 For using XMLConfig: it might be more work up front, but it is much cleaner in the long run.

Comment: I realize this is tagged for wix, however is there a similar solution with number 1 for InstallShield? Or just as good, an explanation of what msi tables are in use with this solution (MoveFile?)?

Comment: The WiX documentation references the relevant MSI table name for each of the elements in the WiX XSD.  For InstallShield you author component conditions in the component view.  For the CopyFile stuff you drill down under the component into Advanced Settings | Other Data and click on the DuplicateFile link.  This will take you to the DuplicateFile table in the direct editor.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung there's a place for XML transformation but it comes at a cost of custom actions.  If the use case supports file A or file B this is cleaner as it's merely a function of installing one file or another without any custom actions.